# Azure JWT Access Tokens - Do they support customizable metadata values from external sources?

Tags: azure

#### Problem

We are seeking to replicate functionality we once had in Auth0 known as [app/user metadata](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/metadata) in which we could inject additional keys and values into a JWT token at the time the user authenticates in order to have identifying information about the user available when they make downstream API requests (pretty much only a few IDs).

To date, we have found one such potential avenue, [custom security attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/custom-security-attributes-overview), which *seems* like it might be what we're looking for, but, we are unable to verify; this is a higher-tier enterprise feature and the documentation, at least to me, doesn't seem to answer the questions I have about the functionality.

#### Custom Security Attributes

- Is there an integration solution in order to connect to an external data source to pull additional key:value pairs (SQL Server, in our situation)?
- Do these attributes support injecting values defined via some sort of API workflow?

If this isn't the route for this sort of functionality, and anyone has any insight on what we should look at, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - It is possible, to use custom attributes and inject additional values, but not in the manner I was hoping.

We have recently met with some technical representatives from Microsoft. The custom security attributes are able to be defined and then pulled in with a user profile, if they are added onto a user via Active Directory.

There is, as of this time, no ability to pull data from external sources, i.e. MS SQL Server, and associate key value pairs to metadata stored on the profiles of the users which can then be pulled in with the JWT Token at time of authentication.

If you are seeking to leverage such features in Azure, and you are seeking to use custom security attributes, your management must be done via Active Directory.